# My React native button text is not appearing in iOS but in android it works fine

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

In my react native application I have used tochableOpacity for my buttons. I have created a custom button component and Have reused it through out the Application. My Custom button component is look like this.

```
const SubmitButton = (props) => {
  const { onpress, btext, loadding, disabled, scrollView } = props;
  const isLargeScreen = useIsLargeDevice();
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={scrollView ? styles.sendButtonScrollView : styles.sendButton}
      onPress={onpress}
      disabled={disabled}>
      {loadding ? (
        <Image
          source={spinner}
          style={scrollView ? styles.bimageScrollview : styles.bimage}
        />
      ) : (
          <Text
            style={[
              styles.sendButtonText,
              isLargeScreen ? styles.largeText : styles.text,
            ]}>

            {btext}
          </Text>
        )}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default SubmitButton;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sendButton: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#3e92ff',
    paddingTop: '6%',
    paddingBottom: '6%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
    marginTop: 25,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    // flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  sendButtonScrollView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#3e92ff',
    paddingTop: '3%',
    paddingBottom: '3%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 50,
    marginTop: 25,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  sendButtonText: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    color: '#ffffff',
    fontWeight: '300',

    textAlign: 'center',
    letterSpacing: 2,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: normalize(14),
  },
  largeText: {
    fontSize: normalize(13),
  },
  bimage: {
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
  },
  bimageScrollview: {
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
  },
});
```

And I have used it in another component like this.

```
Platform.OS === 'ios' ? Icon.loadFont() : null;

const handleBackButton = () => {
  return true;
};

const _navigateToLogin = (navigation) => {
  navigation.navigate('Login');
};

const _onPress = (values, validateToken) => {
  validateToken(values.token);
};

const Tocken = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);
  }, [props.navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.validtoken === true) {
      _navigateToLogin(props.navigation);
      props.cleardata();
    }
  }, [props]);
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} enabled behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'height' : null}>
      <View style={styles.colmty} />
      <View style={styles.formContainer}>
        <AppText styles={styles.loginFormTitle}>
          {strings('token.title')}
        </AppText>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            token: '',
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object({
            token: Yup.string().required(strings('token.token-validation')),
          })}
          onSubmit={(values, formikActions) => {
            _onPress(values, props.validatetoken);
            setTimeout(() => {
              formikActions.setSubmitting(false);
            }, 500);
          }}>
          {(formprops) => (
            <View>
              <View
                style={
                  !formprops.values.token &&
                    !formprops.errors.token &&
                    !props.hasError
                    ? styles.inputView
                    : formprops.values.token &&
                      !formprops.errors.token &&
                      !props.hasError
                      ? styles.validInputView
                      : styles.inputViewError
                }>
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.textField}
                  placeholder={strings('token.token_place_holder')}
                  placeholderTextColor="#bbbbbb"
                  value={formprops.values.token}
                  onChangeText={formprops.handleChange('token')}
                  onBlur={formprops.handleBlur('token')}
                  keyboardType="default"
                />
                {formprops.errors.token || props.hasError ? (
                  <Icon
                    name="times"
                    size={normalize(15)}
                    style={styles.errorIcon}
                  />
                ) : null}
                {formprops.values.token &&
                  !formprops.errors.token &&
                  !props.hasError ? (
                    <Icon
                      name="check"
                      size={normalize(15)}
                      style={styles.validIcon}
                    />
                  ) : null}
              </View>
              {formprops.touched.token &&
                formprops.errors.token &&
                !props.hasError ? (
                  <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                    <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                      {formprops.errors.token}
                    </AppText>
                  </View>
                ) : null}
              {props.hasError ? (
                <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                  <AppText styles={styles.errorMessageText}>
                    {props.error}
                  </AppText>
                </View>
              ) : null}
              <View style={styles.submitButtonView}>
                <SubmitButton
                  btext={strings('token.submit')}
                  onpress={formprops.handleSubmit}
                  loadding={props.loadding}
                  disabled={props.loadding}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.colmty2} />
      <View style={styles.hr} />
      <View style={styles.versionContainer}>
        <AppText styles={styles.version}>version: {version}</AppText>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    loadding: state.signin.loadding,
    validtoken: state.signin.validtoken,
    hasError: state.signin.tokenEr,
    error: state.signin.error,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    validatetoken: (value) => dispatch(signinActions.validatetoken(value)),
    cleardata: () => dispatch(signinActions.cleardata()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Tocken);
```

styles that I have used in the Token component is looks like this.

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import normalize from '_utils/fontsize';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  colmty: {
    height: '20%',
  },
  formContainer: {
    height: '55%',
    // backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    // elevation: 5,
    padding: '10%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingBottom: '5%',
  },
  colmty2: {
    height: '10%',
  },
  bottom: {
    height: '15%',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  hr: {
    borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3',
    borderBottomWidth: 2.0,
    marginRight: '10%',
    marginLeft: '10%',
  },
  validIcon: {
    marginTop: 15,
    color: '#3e92ff',
  },
  errorIcon: {
    marginTop: 15,
    color: '#ff3d3d',
  },
  textField: {
    flex: 1,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium',
    fontSize: normalize(15),
    fontWeight: '500',
    paddingLeft: 0,
  },
  inputView: {
    marginTop: '5%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: '#cccccc',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
  },
  validInputView: {
    marginTop: '5%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: '#3e92ff',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
  },
  inputViewError: {
    marginTop: '5%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderBottomColor: '#ff3d3d',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
  },
  patientFormTitle: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: '200',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#444444',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  bottomLinkText: {
    fontSize: 13,
    color: '#484848',
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3',
  },
  loginFormTitle: {
    fontSize: normalize(16),
    fontWeight: '200',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#444444',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: '-10%',
  },
  errorMessageText: {
    color: '#ff3d3d',
    fontSize: normalize(13),
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  spinnerContainer: {
    marginTop: '50%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  versionContainer: {
    marginRight: '10%',
    marginLeft: '10%',
    marginTop: '10%',
  },
  version: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: normalize(12),
  },
});

export default styles;
```

But button is not showing the text it looks like this.

[image]

I tried lot to find out where I have done wrong but I was unable to do so. Can someone help me to solve this issue.Thank you

Comment: in your custom button component, from where did you import TouchableOpacity? I had problems with TouchableOpacity when I imported from "react-native-gesture-handler"

Comment: @Anukool I import from react-native

Comment: make a snack, if you put hardcode text still the same ?

Comment: @anthonywillismuñoz Yes even for hard code text still the same